# Unable to Connect to MSSQL from NODEJS with SSL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

I am trying to connect to Sql Server Database using Node.js

Below is the code :

```
var express  = require('express');
var sql = require('mssql');
var app      = express(); 

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   var config = {
     server: 'server',
     database: 'database',
     user: 'user',
     password: 'password',
     options: {
       encrypt: true,
       trustServerCertificate:false
     }
   };

   sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        console.log("preparing request");

        request.query("some query").then(function (recordSet) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.send(recordset);
        });
  });

});

app.listen(8080);
```

I get the log: "preparing request". After that nothing happens. There isn't any error log either.

In Java I connect to my DB using following URL:
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://servername;SSL=request

Comment: You're using promises to make your query but aren't catching the errors. The line `if (err) console.log(err);` is wrong - what is `err`? You need to add a `.catch()` method after the `then`.

Comment: I removed the section you mentioned still no response. After calling request.query no response.

Comment: Sorry - I meant that your query might be throwing an error but you are silently ignoring it. Until you add a `.catch` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did the same, and able to figure out actual problem.